# Remove the duplicates from the values list of a key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a better way to remove the duplicates and only keep the minimum value for each key in my dictionary without looping into the dictionary and without creating a new dictionary to append in it?

```
dic2 = {}
dic = {0: [4, 4, 4, 4, 5], 1: [3, 4, 4, 4]}
for key, value in dic.items():
    min_value = min(value)
    dic2[key] = min_value
print(dic2)
```

output

```
{0: 4, 1: 3}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
dic2 = {k: min(v) for k, v in dic.items()}
```

Comment: Is that faster? It is shorter ;)

Comment: It's an answer to the question. Neither "short" nor "fast" were part of it.

Comment: True ;), the OP only added the word fast as a comment to my suggestion. I meant "better" as per the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I would be perfectly happy with your solution. The two dictionaries are not the same, they are distinct, so I don't see the benefit in *modifying* the original. I would reduce by a line though:

```
dic2 = {}
dic = {0: [4, 4, 4, 4, 5], 1: [3, 4, 4, 4]}
for key, value in dic.items():
    dic2[key] = min(value)
print(dic2)
```

Comment: for big dictionaries it takes more time,that's why I was trying to make it fast